# Is there a linux distribution with prebuilt ffmpeg & alsa

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm working on a camcorder example where I need ffmpeg & alsa. Before I actually bake an os for this, just looking around if there is a Distribution that gives ffmpeg & alsa preinstalled.

Raspbian doesn't come with ffmpeg, it has to be built from source so, it would be better if ffmpeg came out of the box. If this is not available I'll have to make one recipe for the same, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone still wants to use H264 with the Raspberry Pi, please follow [this](https://github.com/legotheboss/YouTube-files/wiki/(RPi)-Compile-FFmpeg-with-the-OpenMAX-H.264-GPU-acceleration)
more reference [here](http://hannes.enjoys.it/blog/2016/03/ffmpeg-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi/#comment-5065)

Tested on Pi B & Pi3 B with openmx. Offloads the cpu giving you enough cycles to do other tasks.

Comment: "Tested on Pi B & Pi3 B with openmx" - I think you mean OpenMAX?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried avconv from the raspbian package 'libav-tools'?   It claims to be a drop-in replacement for ffmpeg.

If that doesn't suit, Alpine linux is a distribution with ARM support that packages ffmpeg.